# Running two scripts in parallel in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I have two scripts, server.py and client.py.

I want to be able to start them running, in that order, with one action.

How can achieve that in Pycharm?  Please note that I want to be able to set breakpoints

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can give [Multirun](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7248-multirun) a try:

> Allows to run multiple run configurations at once: group multiple run
>   configurations and start them in a single click. Not only application
>   and test run configurations can be grouped, but other Multirun
>   configurations can be organized into single run configuration.

It will let you run all configurations in `Debug` mode and use breakpoints.

Answer (score 30):

You can also do:

1. Run -> Edit Configurations...
2. Find and add a new "Compound" project
3. Add your configurations into a single component
4. Run it

Answer (score 21):

Run -> Edit Configurations...
Edit your script configuration
Check the "Allow parallel run" checkbox at the top

Then just run then normally.
You can also pin run tab to not be closed

Comment: PyCharm 2023.2.5 (Professional Edition) it's Run -> Edit Configurations -> Modify Options (dropdown) -> allow multiple instances

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of PyCharm (2023.3), you can enable parallel execution by selecting the **Allow multiple instances** option. To do this, navigate to `Run -> Edit Configurations -> Modify Options` and check the corresponding box.

[image: Allow multiple instances (Parallel)]