# running two python script in parallel in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, parallels

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517055/running-two-scripts-in-parallel-in-pycharm) question but I am not sure I got it correctly or not.

I have opened pycharm and one python script and its running (it's topic modeling).

Also I have another python script in which I opened in another pycharm in the same server. I also run it.

Now these two program are running in the same server, I should mention that I have not changed any configuration neither server nor pycharm.

Do you think its ok in this way? or one script technically won't run(in terms of progressing I mean it just show its running but practically wont run) until the other script finished?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, PyCharm will create independent processes on the server, so both scripts will run. You can check it with something like `htop` - search for processes and verify that they're running.

Second, you don't have to open second PyCharm window to run the second script. You can run both of them from the single one. There are at least two ways: with [run configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html) or by spawning multiple [terminal windows](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-tools-terminal.html) and running scripts from there.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, I got GC error while I was running one python script in pycharm and one java in IntelliJ. I have 500gig ram so it was weird to me raising this error. that's why I was suspicious what is happening behind the scence

Comment: Glad I helped, GC error might be because Java can't use your whole memory, you should raise an upper boundary in Help -> Edit Custom VM Options: https://superuser.com/a/1141412/659142

Comment: In the run configuraiton there's a box that let's you tick `allow parallel run`, which will then allow you to simply click the run button multiple times and it will run in parallel

Answer (score 31):

`Edit Configurations` -> `Allow parallel run`. Done

[image]

Comment: Can I allow parallel run by default for all configurations? Or I need to check it for each configuration (which gets pretty annoying).

Answer (score 8):

From the **Run/Debug Configurations** windows you can add a **Compound** configuration that contains multiple configurations that will run in parallel. The **Allow parallel run** option for child configurations make no difference in this case.

[image]

Comment: This allowed me to run more than one script in parallel, but didn't allow me to run the same script twice in parallel

Answer (score 3):

The default behaviour was changed starting from version 2018.3. You can allow multiple runs by selecting **Allow parallel run** within the **Edit Configurations** menu.