# Django test api while api is running in dev environment

Tags: django

I have a Django project in Dev Env. I can run the api with `'python manage.py runserver'`

I can run the tests with `'python manage.py rest api.tests'`

But only one at a time. When I run tests the api is not running. How can I run tests when api is running? I am using Pycharm it does now allow to run same instance twice. Isn't this is a common scenario?

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean. You should just be able to run them as two separate processes - you'll need to provide more details about how exactly you're trying to run them and what fails when you run them both at the same time.

Comment: How do we run them as two separate processes? Two IDE? I use Py Charm which only allow  one instance

Comment: [running two python script in parallel in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51297102/running-two-python-script-in-parallel-in-pycharm)

Comment: I think you can use python runserver and tests parallelly in two terminals. Did you try that.